# How to read an arbitrary number of ints that are in the range 0-50 and count the occurences of each entered

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing this as a practice problem for arrays and I am having a hard time figuring out how to get it to actually count the input.

The full problem reads:

"Design and implement an application that reads an arbitrary number of integers that are in the range 0 to 50 inclusive and counts how many occurrences of each are entered. After all input has been processed, print all of the values (with the number of occurrences) that were entered one ore more times."

Perhaps the chapter didn't explain much or I am just not grasping the concept but I can't think of any way to really get started on this. I've looked around on Google and some of the solutions that were posted still don't make sense (some don't even work when I tested to see what they did!) and was hoping I could get some pointers on what to do here.

My code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = new int[51];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");

    while (input.hasNext()){    
        int x = input.nextInt();
        if (x>=0 && x<=50) // 
            array[x]++; //should make array size equal to x + 1?
    }
}
```

hopefully I'm on the right track here.

Comment: Wow, what a constructive comment @ambigram_maker ...

Comment: `array[x]++` doesn't increase array size, like your comment says... it increases the value of the number stored at position `x` by 1. Initially the value at position `x` is 0. So when you call `array[x]++`, where x=5(for example), the value at position 5 will increase by 1, meaning that there was an occurrence of 5. There still a chunk of code missing (output I guess)

Comment: I don't think 'hasNext' is blocking so might not be appropriate to use with 'System.in', also you should use 'hasNextInt' with 'nextInt'. 

@Serhiy It seems that they are using array[i] to store the number of occurrences of i, which seems sensible, but the comment is confusing.

Comment: @selig `hasNext()` can in fact block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from jedwards reply, I suppose you need the individual occurance of all accepted input. If that is the case try this

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OccuranceCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number or -1 to quit");
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            int x = input.nextInt();
            if (x >= 0 && x <= 50){
                Integer val = counter.get(x);
                if(val == null){
                    counter.put(x, 1);
                } else {
                    counter.put(x, ++val);
                }
            } else if(x == -1){
                break;
            }
        }

        for(Integer key : counter.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key + " occured " + counter.get(key) + " times");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thing #1: You never made a way to stop the `while (input.hasNext()){` loop.
So its going to go on forever just trying to read in integers.

Do to the way `Scanner#hasNext()` works with `System.in`, it will always either return true OR it will stop executing until you enter something, then it will return true again.

A way to fix this is change "input.hasNext()" to "input.hasNext**Int**()"
so, once they enter something that is **not** an integer, the loop will stop and you can do whatever output with the array.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't notice hasNext(), this method used with files. So you know if there're still tokens left or not. Use another thing to break the wile loop, check for something that if the user entered it, it means they done entering data. for example you can use a specific number.

You're on the right track. After you finish reading from the user, run a for loop to check if the value of the array element is greater than 1, then you print it:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     if(array[i] > 1)
          System.out.println("The number: " + i + " entered " + array[i] + "times");
 }
```

as simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int count = 0;



        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number (enter a non-integer to end)");
            try{
                int x = input.nextInt();
                array.add(x);
                if (x>=0 && x<=50) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.format("The numbers you entered were: %s\n", array);
        System.out.format("The count of in-range numbers was: %d\n", count);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter a number (enter a non-integer to end)
1
Please enter a number (enter a non-integer to end)
2
Please enter a number (enter a non-integer to end)
3
Please enter a number (enter a non-integer to end)
-1
Please enter a number (enter a non-integer to end)
100
Please enter a number (enter a non-integer to end)
e

The numbers you entered were: [1, 2, 3, -1, 100]
The count of in-range numbers was: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's answered, but you're supposed to be learning array stuff, and the accepted answer is a hashmap, so I'm going to write you a more array-centric version. You were close for the record.

```
int[] result = new int[51];

//this should run until you enter something that's not an int. 
//I'm leaving out print statements, and the check for 0<=x<=50
while(input.hasNextInt())
{
   result[input.nextInt()]++;        
}

for(int i = 0; i<=50;i++)
{
   if(results[i]>0)
   {
      //print something like (i+": " + results[i] + "\n")
   }
}
```

Let me know if you need help understanding any of it. Although you'll probably enjoy it more if you throw it in your compiler and play around with it yourself till you get what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OccuranceCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number or -1 to quit");
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            int x = input.nextInt();
            if (x >= 0 && x <= 50){
                Integer val = counter.get(x);
                if(val == null){
                    counter.put(x, 1);
                } else {
                    counter.put(x, ++val);
                }
            } else if(x == -1){
                break;
            }
        }

        for(Integer key : counter.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key + " occured " + counter.get(key) + " times");
        }
    }
}
```

Try this, it works very well (by JovanDaGreat).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Chap7ProjSP2022 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // declaring variables
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int [] store = new int [51];
    int input = 0;
        
    System.out.println("Enter arbitrary number of integers that are in the range 0 to 50");
    System.out.println("Enter integer not in the range 0 to 50 to end loop and process\nEnter integer:");
    input = scan.nextInt();
    
    // storing inputed numbers
    while (input >= 0 && input <= 50)
    {
        store[input] += 1;
        System.out.println("Enter integer:");
        input = scan.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    // printing numbers
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        if (store[i] > 0)
            System.out.println(i + ": " + store[i]);
    }
                
}

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).