# How to insert inputted integers from user into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I just had my lesson on Arrays yesterday in my AP Computer Science class and am working on an assignment that has to do with taking in integers and putting them in an array. I haven't learned how to make a table nor how to make 2d and 3d arrays if I even know what they are. Anyways, the project I am working on is here:

"Design and implement an application that reads an arbitrary number of integers that are in the range 0 to 50 inclusive and counts how many occurrences of each are entered. After all input has been processed, print all of the values (with the number of occurrences) that were entered one or more times."

I have already found possible solutions on Stack Overflow [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635211/how-to-read-an-arbitrary-number-of-ints-that-are-in-the-range-0-50-and-count-the)

but I did not learn hashmap or map yet and the output of their solutions isn't the one that I am suppose to be getting.

What I know about my question is how to print the first row of the array which would look something like this but without the table:

[Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnEAw.jpg)

What I do not know is how to add another row and how to count how many integers the user inputted and how many times of the same number.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Si
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    final int LIMIT = 50;
    int[] numbers = new int[LIMIT];




    System.out.println("Enter an integer (-1 to quit");
    int integer = scan.nextInt();

    while (integer != -1)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter " + integer + " integers between 0 and 50");
        int number = scan.nextInt();
        if (integer >=0 && integer <= 50){
            for (int num = 0; num <= LIMIT; num++){//to make a row from 0 to 50
                number[scan.nextInt()]++;//count the integer the user inputs
                System.out.println (numbers[num] + "  ");//not sure how to continue, I am not sure exactly if i understand the few codes that I typed above

                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I think that the codes underneath my for loop aren't correct but I am not sure what I can do instead that will make it work. Here is what a possible output could look like:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9... 48  49  50     //Row from 1 to 50
3  1  0  2  0  0  0  3  1     0  0   0      //user typed "1" 3 times, typed "2" 1 time...
```

Comment: This seems to be very related to your problem, although not identical: [Counting occurences of integers in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855544/counting-occurences-of-integers-in-a-java-array/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not willing to use `HashMap` or `ArrayList`, then this task can be achieved by using two arrays. One array let's call it `nums` that holds all the integers ranging from `0 to 50` and another array called `occur` that holds the occurrence of each entered number.
Now, to process the inputs, you need to keep on taking inputs from the user till he enters `-1`(If that's what I assumed to be correct according to problem statement).
So, the basic steps needed to achieve this are listed below:

1. Create an infinite loop
2. Start taking the inputs. Lets say `n = scanner.nextInt()`
3. If the entered value `n` is greater than 50, just ignore it.
4. Add this entered value into `nums[n]` and at the same time increment
   the `nth` value in the `occur[n]`.
5. Break out of the loop if `n == -1`.

Now, the code snippet should be looking like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] nums = new int[51]; //Array size is 51 since it should hold numbers from 0 to 50 inclusive.
    int[]occur = new int[51];


    for(;;){
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        if(n > 50){
            continue;
        }
        if(n == -1){
            break;
        }
        occur[n] += 1;
        nums[n] = n;
    }
```

Later, when the control breaks out of the loop, you can iterate both `nums` and `occur` and display the results like this:

```
System.out.println("All Numbers entered:");
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("All Occurrences: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < occur.length; i++){
            System.out.print(occur[i] + " ");
        }
```

And hence, the complete method should be like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] nums = new int[51];
        int[]occur = new int[51];


        for(;;){
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            if(n > 50){
                continue;
            }
            if(n == -1){
                break;
            }
            occur[n] += 1;
            nums[n] = n;
        }

        System.out.println("All Numbers entered:");
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("All Occurrences: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < occur.length; i++){
            System.out.print(occur[i] + " ");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
```

One possible output generated by this code snippet looks like this:

```
All Numbers entered:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
All Occurrences: 
1 3 5 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2
```

I think this is what you were trying to achieve and I hope this helps you in your learning.

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of things.

Using a while loop is a good first step! Where I think you are going wrong is with the

```
for (int num = 0; num <= LIMIT; num++){//to make a row from 0 to 50
```

You don't need to be doing this every time within the while loop. Get all the information from the user (until the user enters -1) and then print everything afterwards.

A good way to think about storing your occurrences is to make an array that is of length 50 (like you have done) and incrementing the index that corresponds with the number that the user entered (remember that arrays are 0-indexed). Then you can just print 2 lines with one line being the numbers 1 through 50 and the other line is printed by using a simple for loop and the print statement.

This was meant to help you without working out the solution for you especially because this seems to be a homework problem and it is important to try to figure out these concepts by yourself! If you have more questions feel free to ask!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! However, could you tell me how to increment the index that ~corresponds~ with the number that the user enters?

Comment: Well you don't really need to increment any indexes. When you get input from the user check that it falls within your desired range and then simply say `array[userInput-1]++`. The reason that we do `userInput-1` is because arrays are 0 indexed!

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will helpfull... it will break input at -1...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] number = new int[50];

    System.out.print("Enter the integers between 0 to 50: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        int a = input.nextInt();
        number[a] += a;
        if (a == -1)
            break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        if (number[i] != -1) {
            if (number[i] / i > 1)
                System.out.println(i + " occurs " + number[i] / i + " times");
            else
                System.out.println(i + " occurs " + number[i] / i + " time");               }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: In the question, "System.out.println("Enter an integer (-1 to quit");"

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I used your code but when I typed -1, i get an out of bound exception error because  `number[a] += a;` can't store  "-1"

Answer (score 0):

The following will do, you need Java8 though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,1,  2,  3, 1);
    int find = 1;
    System.out.println(list.stream().filter(x->x==find).toArray().length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started following @Shyam Baitmangalkar his directions on how to do it and I made some small adjustments with the scanner and sort of completed my expectations. However, sometimes when I enter "-1" it does not quit. I also have to enter many integers before quiting. I think what the problem is that somehow the if statements are not being executed. Anyways, here is my final code that I came up with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class asdf
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] nums = new int[51];
        int[]occur = new int[51];

        System.out.println("Enter an integer (-1 to quit)");
        int integer = sc.nextInt();
        //for(int index = 0; index <= integer; index++ ){
        for(;;){
            System.out.println("Enter an integer");
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            if(n > 50){
                continue;
            }
            if(n == -1){
                break;
            }
            occur[n] += 1;
            nums[n] = n;
        }

        System.out.println("All Numbers entered:");
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("All Occurrences: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < occur.length; i++){
            System.out.print(occur[i] + " ");
        }
        sc.close();
}
}
```

Output:

```
Enter an integer
5
Enter an integer
3
Enter an integer
34
Enter an integer
5
Enter an integer
7
Enter an integer
5
Enter an integer
3
Enter an integer
2
Enter an integer
4
Enter an integer
6
Enter an integer
6
Enter an integer
43
Enter an integer
46
Enter an integer
77
Enter an integer
5
Enter an integer
3
Enter an integer
4
Enter an integer
6
Enter an integer
7
Enter an integer
54
Enter an integer
4
Enter an integer
-1
All Numbers entered:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 23 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32 0 34 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 43 0 45 46 0 0 0 0 
All Occurrences: 
0 1 3 11 9 9 8 6 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 1 0 0 0 0
```